# Копирование подписчиков из одного ивента в другой

Tags: c#

Собственно, проблема в следующем. Есть ивент, назовем его Event1 (он из внешней библиотеки), также есть второй ивент Event2. Мне нужно подписчиков Event2 подписать на Event1.

```
Event1 = Event2
```

Соответственно не работает.
Вопрос в том, как это реализовать. Опыта у меня с ивентами очень мало, я бы сказал это первый раз.

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте перефразировал бы вопрос, убрав все, что связано с SFML, так, вам смогут помочь больше людей. "нельзя скопировать просто так", потому что на события подписываются, а не копируют, то есть `+=` или `-=` (подписаться/отписаться). При создание нового объекта у вас естественно он будет пустой, без всех подписей. Я нашёл [данный способ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055038/how-to-clone-control-event-handlers-at-run-time), но не уверен в его работоспособности (вроде как должен скопировать все события в новый объект).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, вам подойдёт такой путь.

Подпишитесь на `Event1`. По приходу события отправляйте `Event2`.

```
class Program
{
    Library library = new Library();
    public event EventHandler Event2;

    public Program()
    {
        library.Event1 += (sender, args) => Event2?.Invoke(this, args);
    }
}

class Library
{
    public event EventHandler Event1;
}
```

Другой путь — объявите `Event2`, не как field-like event, а через `add`/`remove`, и подписывайте присланные делегаты на `Event1`. Сигнатуры событий должны быть совместимы при этом.

```
Library library = new Library();
public event EventHandler Event2
{
    add { library.Event1 += value; }
    remove { library.Event1 -= value; }
}
```

---

Синтаксически более простой путь такой:

```
class Program
{
    void Resubscribe()
    {
        library.Event1 += Event2;
    }

    Library library = new Library();
    public event EventHandler Event2;
}
```

Тут мы пользуемся тем, что field-like event изнутри класса выглядит как делегат совместимого типа.

Недостаток этого метода в том, что мы копируем подписчиков только один раз, и при приходе новых подписчиков синхронизация между подписками теряется.